# Is it possible to run a automatic post clone script in cloud 9 ide

Tags: cloud9-ide

I would like to automate a quick start of SQL-MVC.

Can I set a script to run automatically after a git repo is cloned? like this:

> auto-run.sh

Also, is it possible to launch a browser window to automatically open to the applications URL at the end of the script?

I have checked all the docs, but I don't find anything on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

From the Git book [src](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks):

> It’s important to note that client-side hooks are not copied when you clone a repository. If your intent with these scripts is to enforce a policy, you’ll probably want to do that on the server side; see the example in “[An Example Git-Enforced Policy](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy#_an_example_git_enforced_policy)”.

So, the automatic running of a script on clone is not going to work. However, you can commit the `auto-run.sh` file within your repository and ask the user to run that after cloning.

You can open a new browser window on your local machine by adding the correct command within the shell script, (for example, on a mac I usually just use `open`). However, since Cloud9 workspace doesn't have a window manager, you won't be able to do that from the Cloud9 Terminal. One way to open a browser pane within Cloud9 IDE (not in another tab, I don't think that's possible) is to echo the url, and ask the user to click on it at the end of the script, so something like this:

`Please click https://www.google.com to continue`

and the Cloud9 terminal is smart enough to open the url in a new browser pane within the IDE when the user clicks on the url.

Comment: Yea, I am giving the user step by step instructions like this :  https://github.com/quale-quest/sql-mvc-c9/blob/master/README.md , but I was hoping to automate the whole process. Even if it cant be done via git, it would be great is c9 had a way to make this seamless.

Comment: "is to echo the url" ... how would I get the c9 application URL from a shell (or node) script?

Comment: The base url is http://<workspace-name>-<username>.c9.io for the app running at port 8080 (which is forwarded)

Comment: Sorry, missed your earlier comment. I see that you need to find a generic way to do it. You can use the $C9_HOSTNAME environment variable to get the current workspace's hostname

Comment: Even though executing code on git clone is not going to be feasible imo for security reasons, I think the above method I outlined should reduce the multiple steps you have in your readme to just a couple of steps: execute, then click on the url.